# Converting company name to ticker

Tags: python, parsing, nltk

Hey so I have an excel document that has a mapping of company names to their respective tickers. I currently have this function

```
def(ticker):
    mapping = pd.read_excel('ticker.xlsx',header = 3,parse_cols='A,B')
        for index,row in mapping.iterrows():
            if ticker.upper() in row['Name'].upper().split():
                ticker = row['Ticker']
    return ticker
```

The reason I am using "in" on line 4 instead of "==" is because in the excel document "Apple" is listed as "Apple Inc." and since the user isn't likely to type that I want ticker("apple") to return "AAPL".

In the code above the if statement never gets executed and I was curious on the best possible solution here.

Comment: You should post some sample data, especially data that is supposed to trigger the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Havnt seen this type of syntax before. Must be the nltk syntax.

That being said I will try to be helpful.

If the **In** command is the same as SQL then it means exactly equal. Meaning 'Apple' in('Apple Inc') would be false.

You want to do a if('AppleInc **like** '%Apple%')
or perhaps a .Match using regex. That's about the extent to which I can make suggestions as I don't do python.